# jquery form validation not working as intended

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Updated current codes for visibility. I am working on a .php file if that matters.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.error').html("");

    if ($.trim($('input[name="content_id"]').val()) == '' || ($.trim($('input[name="title"]').val()) == '') || ($.trim($('input[name="image"]').val()) == '')) {

      $('.error').append(" Please ensure all required fields are filled in.");
      return false;
    } else {
      $('.error').html("*");
      $('form').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

<form method="POST" action="display.php" id="my-form">
  <!--onSubmit="return validateForm()"-->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>content_id</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>image</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="content_id" size="26"> <span class="error">*</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="title" size="26"> <span class="error">*</span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="image" size="26"> <span class="error">*</span></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel"> <a href="index.php" /></a>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: there is nothing like `e.preventdefault();` . it's `e.preventDefault();`. check here:- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp  (capital `D`)

Answer (score 0):

1. you have an error in you script you are closing the if in the first line
2. `e.preventdefault()` is nothing infact `e.preventDefault()`.
3. you are appending to wrong class name , the class name is `.error` but you are appending to `.errors` .
4. use form submit event `$("#my-form").on('submit', function(e) {`

see below it works as you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.error').html("");

    if ($.trim($('input[name="content_id"]').val()) == '' || ($.trim($('input[name="title"]').val()) == '') || ($.trim($('input[name="image"]').val()) == '')) {

      $('.error').append(" Please ensure all required fields are filled in.");
      return false;
    } else {
      $('.error').html("*");
      $('form').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

<form method="POST" action="display.php" id="my-form">
  <!--onSubmit="return validateForm()"-->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>content_id</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>image</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="content_id" size="26"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $cErr;?></span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="title" size="26"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $tErr;?></span></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="image" size="26"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $iErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel"> <a href="index.php" /></a>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if you hit submit multiple time. it will append error message multiple time. correct that

Comment: He also can change `$('input[type="submit"]')` to `$('button[type="submit"]')`

Comment: Have tried the code but it is not working. I am working with a form in .php https://pastebin.com/nxGRta5q

Comment: did you provided the id to the form while using my solution.

Comment: you must add the jquery in the  head of the html document rather than inside the body,  strange that it isnt working , add you code as a code snippet

Comment: are you getting any errors on the console? are there any other custom scripts that you are running on that page?

Comment: Updated code snippet, 1 error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at form.php:8 No other scripts.

Comment: you are not including the jquery library on top inside head , you must include it before the js calls like `$(document).ready()`

Comment: My bad, that fixed the console error but the jquery validation is still not working.

Comment: have you hosted it somewhere , any live link of that form ? that i can look into

Comment: It's on a localhost, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have made some mistakes as @Muhammad Omer Aslam mention but I think you are looking for this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
            $("input").each(function(){
                if ($.trim($(this).val()) == ''){
                   $(this).next('.errors').html("* Please ensure all required fields are filled in.");
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).next('.errors').html("Filled");
                    $('form').submit();
                }
                
            })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

<form method="POST" action="display.php"> 
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>content_id</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>image</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="content_id" size="26"> <span class="errors">*</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title" size="26"> <span class="errors">*</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="image" size="26"> <span class="errors">*</span></td>
  </tr>

</table>

  <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel"> <a href="index.php"/>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Have tried the code but it is not working. I am working with a form in .php

Comment: @Ryan Put jquery library in the head before your jquery code and tell me if works. My example works fine.